# Floating Action Button rendering as oval on lower end devices

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I am using a floating action button (without using third part library)

The fab appears fine on mdpi and hdpi devices but appears as a distinctive oval shape on ldpi devices

For reference here are the screenshots -

1. Here is the fab rendering fine on mdpi devices

[image: The fab rendering fine]

2. Here is the fab rendering as an oval on ldpi devices

[image]

The main layout has an include element to include the fab layout . The fab layout includes a background as a drawable . background=@drawable/fab_drawable

A. fab_drawable.xml in res/drawable

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:top="8px">
    <layer-list>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="oval">
                <solid android:color="#14000000"/>
                <padding
                    android:bottom="1px"
                    android:left="0px"
                    android:right="1px"
                    android:top="1px"
                    />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="oval">
                <solid android:color="#15000000"/>
                <padding
                    android:bottom="1px"
                    android:left="0px"
                    android:right="1px"
                    android:top="1px"
                    />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="oval">
                <solid android:color="#16000000"/>
                <padding
                    android:bottom="1px"
                    android:left="0px"
                    android:right="1px"
                    android:top="1px"
                    />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="oval">
                <solid android:color="#17000000"/>
                <padding
                    android:bottom="1px"
                    android:left="0px"
                    android:right="1px"
                    android:top="1px"
                    />
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
</item>
<item android:id="@+id/fab_drawable_shape">
    <shape android:shape="oval" >
        <solid android:color="#404952" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/onboarding_selector"/>
```

B. fab_drawable.xml in drawable-v21

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:color="?android:colorControlHighlight" >

<item>
    <shape android:shape="oval" >
        <solid android:color="?android:colorAccent" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

C. In my basefragment i am checking if build is lollipop then use this clipping code

```
ViewOutlineProvider fabOutlineProvider = new ViewOutlineProvider() {

            @Override
            public void getOutline(View view, Outline outline) {
                int diameter = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(
                        R.dimen.fab_diameter);
                outline.setOval(0, 0, diameter, diameter);
            }
        };

        mComposeFabButtonView.setOutlineProvider(fabOutlineProvider);
        mComposeFabButtonView.setClipToOutline(true);
```

D. The dimensions of the fab button diameter are 60sp for all devices

Comment: I don't think ldpi devices exit anymore

Comment: But the team i am part of requires the design to be consistent across a range of devices

Comment: which board are you referring to ?

Comment: I wanted to mean , across all devices

Comment: I see, but what if there are not ldpi devices on the market ?

Comment: Can you post you implementation of the fab so we can help? Also do you have a values-ldpi or values-mdpi folder as you might be over riding them values in there.

Comment: @Blackbelt I still proudly own **2** ldpi devices. And according to the [dashboard](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html?utm_source=suzunone), they are still the **4.4%** of the global market.

Comment: @DerGolem which one?

Comment: **1** - use `dp` instead of `px`. **2** - there is some **asymmetry** in your paddings (1, 0, 1, 1).

Comment: @DerGolem - Thanks that solved it . I was of the opinion that the asymmetry was in place for creating the shadow layers on pre lollipop devices , but it seems the asymmetry was causing the problem

Answer (score 1):

I solved the rendering issue by making the padding details in the layer list items to be **1 dp for all sides**

Here is the code -

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:top="8dp">
    <layer-list>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="oval">
                <solid android:color="#14000000"/>
                <padding
                    android:bottom="1dp" <--- Here are the changes
                    android:left="1dp"   <---
                    android:right="1dp"  <---
                    android:top="1dp"    <---
                    />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="oval">
                <solid android:color="#15000000"/>
                <padding
                    android:bottom="1dp"
                    android:left="1dp"
                    android:right="1dp"
                    android:top="1dp"
                    />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="oval">
                <solid android:color="#16000000"/>
                <padding
                    android:bottom="1dp"
                    android:left="1dp"
                    android:right="1dp"
                    android:top="1dp"
                    />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="oval">
                <solid android:color="#17000000"/>
                <padding
                    android:bottom="1dp"
                    android:left="1dp"
                    android:right="1dp"
                    android:top="1dp"
                    />
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
</item>
<item android:id="@+id/fab_drawable_shape">
    <shape android:shape="oval" >
        <solid android:color="#404952" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/onboarding_selector"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the dimension from `sp` to `dp`. Hopefully, it will solve the problem.

If not, but the FAB inside a separate layout and give that layout the `dp` dimensions. FAB should use `match_parent` x2.

Answer (score 0):

Only use `SP` for defining the font size, as it changes size if the user has the large text option enabled. For all other purposes use `dp`. For more information refer to [What is the difference between "px", "dp", "dip" and "sp" on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-between-px-dp-dip-and-sp-in-android)

Also it would be best to use a library like [Makovkastar's Floating Action Button Library](https://github.com/makovkastar/FloatingActionButton).

Hope this helps

Comment: Well our app is pretty close to the 65K limit of method references and i thought of achieving the fab button without any dependency .